# Multi-resolution layout

Tags: html, css, templates

I came across this awesome website this morning:

http://mediaqueri.es

What is the best way to manage all 4 resolutions when designing a website? 4 different layouts, and switch between them depending on the client's screen resolution? Is there something smarter to do maybe, like some kind of "dynamic layout"?

Comment: 4 differently sized layouts != 4 resolutions.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I agree a single layout can work for a whole set of resolutions, like "between 320 and 480 pixels". Is that what you are saying?

Comment: what do you mean? the link you provided IS a dynamic layout.. Have you scaled the page? I think these are nice techniques. I'm totally convinced that (semi) liquid layouts are back. As for the scaling of the images. You cant just give each image a width of a certain percentage. Don't forget to also declare the max-width as the original image width, or your images will become blurry.

Comment: Hi Jules, I didn't try to scale the pages, sorry. I understand better how that works now. That's really impressive... But unfortunately it doesn't work with IE 7/8. It does with IE 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Queries are a part of CSS 3, and that webpage is an example of them in practice. The idea is that you can specify different CSS files based on screen/print, as well as available device resolution and other parameters.

Some relevant links:

- [Pros and Cons of 6 CSS Layout Patterns](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-layout-patterns-part-2/)
- [W3C Media Queries Proposal](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)
- [How to ...](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

I have not done much with this but I've heard arguments for and against. The alternative is browser detection to determine which css/page to load.